# How to reduce space between lines?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using visual editor as Widget, and i create google fonts in order to choose the letter, color , basically control the fonts.

But i'm not understanding why do I have so many space between lines. How you can see in the picture, I have a lot of space Between Morada and Rua da Praça. And again between 7645 Vila Mova.

can you explain me where and how can I control that space?
[image]

Comment: You have some css properties on your page with define the space between line. if you have for instance line-heigth:20px and use 12px font-size and 4px so there will 4px  distant from the bottom and upper lines. If your page is online, provide the url we could check and suggest you a solution

Comment: This is my link.  http://www.vetalentejano.pt/Contactos/   Thanks for the help. In Typography > Theme Typography i dont see any option to reduce the distance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the page with a browser. See what tags you are having there and what is their styling. For instance, if you open the page with Chrome and open the browser console, by right-clicking and clicking on Inspect Element, then you see the generated html. Click on the tags where you have the problem and see the CSS rules. Try to untick some of the rules until you manage to get rid of the problem. Your last untick is on the CSS rule which yields the problem. If you still did not find the solution, see whether there are tags, like `<br/>` and click on them still in the console, press backspace. If you manage to reduce the gap, then those tags are to blame. If you still did not find the source of the problem, then see the parent of the tags and check their stylings. And so forth, until you find the exact issue.

Comment: Lajos thanks for the help. I dont know how to use the console :( or where to untick things and refresh the page to see the results...

Comment: Kindly read this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/console/console-ui if you open the console, you will see css rules on the right if you click on the elements tab.

Comment: Lajos, thanks a lot! I manage to found what was the problem using the console. Now How can i fix that in wordpress, since i use a theme and ton't touch css ? thanks once again

Comment: My problem is here, but i dont know where to change this:  media="all"
#pl-23 .panel-grid-cell .so-panel {
    /* margin-bottom: 30px;

Comment: @UcanDoIt, kindly search for the string of .panel-grid-cell in your project. Among the results you should find the exact location of the given CSS rule.

Comment: thanks for your help! But this is a widget (visual editor) from worpress i think i don't have acess to the code of this :\

Comment: Then you can do some hacking. Maybe you can add a script like this jQuery("#pl-23 .panel-grid-cell .so-panel").css("margin-bottom", "0px")